# .stopPropagation() placed on input not allowing for input text to be entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I am trying to add column searching to some columns within a table (using Datatables). I am adding the input field for the search into the each header cell of the table. Datatables makes it so that anytime you click on the header it changes the sorting method, so I inserted `.stopPropagation` attached to an on click event for the input field to not change the sorting on the column when the input portion of the header cell is clicked. The only problem is that the `.stopPropagation` is working and not effecting the sort, but when clicking on the input field it doesn't let me add text to the field. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is a snippet of the code (this is placed into the code for creating each table on our site):

```
var columnsearch = $(this).find('th');
        columnsearch.each(function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).append( '<input type="search" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
        })

        var textbox = $(this).find('input')
        textbox.click(function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        })
```

[image: Image of the column search placed within the table header]

Comment: Did you try to use event.preventDefault(); ?

Comment: Yes, tried that and it didn't work. event.PreventDefault() should only prevent the default action of the command, but not prevent DOM bubbling, which is what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging, I found out by using the Event Listeners portion of Chrome's inspector and found that a feature we have enabled on Datatables, colReorder, used to rearrange columns, was interfering on the functionality of the input field with a conflicting `mousedown` event. I added:

```
textbox.mousedown(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
        })
```

to the column search JS piece and that fixed the problem.